# Web scrapping in ESPN NBA Fantasy Log-in error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to access the ESPN NBA Fantasy to automatize the consult of league standing.

I cannot go throug the email step  because I cant find the element to send my email.

This is what I got already:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.get('https://fantasy.espn.com/basketball/league/standings?        leagueId=1940892466&statView=official')
driver.find_element("id", "onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='InputIdentityFlowValue']").send_keys('myemail@gmail.com')
```

But this error message occurs:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='InputIdentityFlowValue']"}
(Session info: chrome=118.0.5993.118)
Stacktrace:
GetHandleVerifier [0x00BC4DE3+43907]
(No symbol) [0x00B50741]
(No symbol) [0x00A433ED]
(No symbol) [0x00A76760]
(No symbol) [0x00A76C2B]
(No symbol) [0x00AA6F62]
(No symbol) [0x00A92BA4]
(No symbol) [0x00AA55CA]
(No symbol) [0x00A92956]
(No symbol) [0x00A6E17E]
(No symbol) [0x00A6F32D]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00E75AF9+2865305]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00EBE78B+3163435]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00EB8441+3138017]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00C4E0F0+605840]
(No symbol) [0x00B5A64C]
(No symbol) [0x00B56638]
(No symbol) [0x00B5675F]
(No symbol) [0x00B48DB7]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x760A7BA9+25]
RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7744BD2B+107]
RtlClearBits [0x7744BCAF+191]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `IFRAME` which is wrapping the desired element. You need to first switch into the `IFRAME` and then perform any actions.

Check the code below:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get('https://fantasy.espn.com/basketball/league/standings?        leagueId=1940892466&statView=official')
driver.find_element("id", "onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()
driver.switch_to.frame("oneid-iframe")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='InputIdentityFlowValue']").send_keys('myemail@gmail.com')
```

Below code should be used to come out of IFRAME once you have performed actions

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

**Suggestion:** Read about IFRAMES from the official documentation here [Working with IFrames and frames](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/)